# Uncaught ArgumentCountError in socialsharoing module in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, prestashop

I can't display product page because I have an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
>   function SocialSharing::hookDisplayRightColumnProduct(), 0 passed in
>   /home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/cache/smarty/compile/82/46/46/82464600fd7c3ffa279ca875a092ea2adffe15f9.file.product.tpl.php
>   on line 668 and exactly 1 expected in
>   /home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/modules/socialsharing/socialsharing.php:254
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/cache/smarty/compile/82/46/46/82464600fd7c3ffa279ca875a092ea2adffe15f9.file.product.tpl.php(668):
>   SocialSharing->hookDisplayRightColumnProduct() #1
>   /home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(188):
>   content_5b98d98abba660_35020479(Object(Smarty_Custom_Template)) #2
>   /home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/classes/SmartyCustom.php(110):
>   Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch('/home/admin/dom...', NULL, NULL,
>   Object(SmartyCustom), false, true, false) #3
>   /home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/classes/control in
>   /home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/modules/socialsharing/socialsharing.php
>   on line 254

I clean prestashop cache. I check socialsharing module, line 254:

```
public function hookDisplayRightColumnProduct($params)
{
    return $this->hookDisplaySocialSharing();
}
```

where is the problem ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Adam below is possibilities.

1. Is there any javascript error? Hit F12 to bring up the developer console, then console tab, look for red entries.
2. Remove socialsharing module and restore it once again.

Please see if this link which may help you: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/446840-native-module-social-sharing-not-work/

Comment: I remove this module. But without any solution. In console I dont see any errors. In source code I dont see header. This is a link: https://vinfaucet.com/pl/baterie-umywalkowe-retro